# Battlefield 3 freezes 5 minutes into the campaign

Tags: battlefield-3, technical-issues

I have a brand new Alienware, hardware is probably not an issue. My laptop freezes about 5 minutes into playing Battlefield 3 campaign. Is there a known fix for this issue? Is this even a known issue ?

Comment: Not to be cynical, but "I have a brand new alienware, hardware is not an issue." is a bad assumption.  I've had to troubleshoot over a half dozen peoples' Alienware machines with driver or hardware issues right out of the box.  My point is: *don't assume* the machine you got has no issues, check for latest drivers and such anyway.

Comment: Nick, I agree. I am also a owner of a brand new M18x (which I use for my job, not gaming ironically enough) I have already had to have my video cards replaced (radeon 6990m's). I know that for my cards at least, there is a special patch for the drivers to play Battlefield 3. Robotsushi I would check out http://forum.notebookreview.com/alienware-m18x/ good forums for alienware.

Comment: Ex. Just because I drive a Ferrari doesn't mean the engine can't have an issue... or the tires, etc. But since Dell has acquired Alienware in 2006, um... at least the case looks nice?

Comment: lol very valid points gentleman. Let me re state that I am fairly confident that hardware is not the issue.

Comment: You are not alone, it does not matter what you play in Battlefield 3 under right circomstanses. I have tried everything, heat, power, lower graphics, disabling sound (bios) nothing seem to work. This seem to be a problem within the Battlefield software, guess they (DICE) are working on it.

Comment: I would install the current GPU drivers FROM YOUR VENDOR first. That is, go to Dell/Alienware support pages and look for the right driver. If you have already installed anything else from AMD/Nvidia download pages, uninstall them right before installing the Dell driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically "how do I determine if my hardware is stable?"

Try

- run [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) overnight and see if your CPU is stable
- run [Memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) overnight and see if your memory is stable
- run [Furmark](http://www.ozone3d.net/benchmarks/fur/) for an hour or so (be careful as this thing loads GPUs far beyond any realistic load)

Warning: Battlefield 3 is known to be *extremely* GPU intensive and may cause more heat than most games.

edit: apparently there might be a possible [RealTek sound driver conflict](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/lo6o0/realtek_crashing_problem_inherited_from_moh/), too. Apparently there's a history of Realtek issues with DICE engine games, so this is not new. A lot of people are [saying "use USB audio" as a workaround](http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield3/comments/lqs7t/this_is_now_becoming_a_huge_issue_not_my_video/). Can you try that?

Comment: I'm trying the USB audio right now...

Comment: @robot don't forget to update your video drivers as well, this can be odd on laptops

Comment: Good news all tests ran with positive results. Bad news BF3 still crashes. Im gonna re-install and see if that fixes it. I just downloaded the newest drivers about a week ago(I literally just got this thing).

Comment: @Robotsushi both nvidia and ati have furiously been releasing new drivers since just before BF3 came out, it is entirely possible for  drivers gotten a week ago to be 1 or 2 revs out of date.

Comment: I got a new update from nvidia a few days ago and this fixed all my problems.

Comment: @Robotsushi See? It's all in the GPU software.

Answer (score 4):

This is a **very** common issue. On the [official EA forums](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/) (via http://battlelog.battlefield.com), [there is a technical support thread with over 500 people reporting the same issue](http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bf3/forum/threadview/2832654347709941160/) (myself included).

Not to dampen your spirits of getting it fixed, but I reformatted my PC, and the problem remained.

Having contacted EA support, their suggestions were as follows;

- Try updating Punkbuster manually (download from http://evenbalance.com)
- Try opening the required ports for Battlefield 3, and try disabling all software (e.g. Windows, AV) and hardware (e.g. router) firewalls.
- Try closing down all other running applications to eliminate an application conflict.

All of these suggestions screamed "Generic troubleshooting attempts", not specifically directed towards the problem.

As mentioned by Jeff, a lot of people have resolved the problem through playing with their sound drivers;

- Disable any sound devices in Device Manager you dont use
- If you have any Realtek sound drivers installed, try uninstalling them so the Windows driver is used instead.
- Try disabling your sound hardware in your BIOS

(Obviously, playing without sound is a bit of a b$%^£.)

But there are still a huge percentage of people who **cannot** resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. In the menu, I could stay for 10 minutes and nothing bad happened. When I played the campagin, I had a black screen after a few minutes of gameplay for an unknown reason.

I have a Geforce GTX 560 Ti OC version (but You said You have a laptop, still I hope You have the same issue with the different gpu).

I fixed it by upgrading the bios of the graphics card. The problem disappeared and I am playing BF3 happily for hours straight without any issues.